# What parameters do azimuthal and transverse cylindrical projection in secant case have as proj4 string

Tags: proj, transverse-mercator, laea, projection-mathematics

conical equal-area projection, secant case has e.g.

```
+proj=aea +lat_1=... +lat_2=... +lon_0=... +lat_0=... +x_0=... +y_0=... etc...
```

I would ask if there is such thing, for transverse cylindrical equal-area, secant case?
e.g:

```
+proj=tcea +lon_1=... +lon_2=... +lon_0=... +lat_0=... +x_0=... +y_0=... etc...
```

and what is for the azimuthal equal area, secant case, I know just this for tangent case

```
+proj=laea +lat_0=... +lon_0=... +x_0=... +y_0=... etc...
```

what should one add to get secant case not only tangent at a point?

**Edit:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The transverse cylindrical equal area projection can be made into a secant case by specifying a scale factor with the `+k_0=` parameter. The secant lines (standard circles) of such a projection do not follow meridians, there are no "standard meridians", and using `+lon_1 +lon_2` would be ambiguous, so they are not used. Therefore we indicate a scale factor that will allow two small circles to be standard (no distortion).

The Lambert azimuthal equal area projection is tangent, there is no secant case. In fact, if we tried to create a secant version of an azimuthal equal area projection, we would get very odd results, where the center of the projection would become a sort of singularity and directions would be undetermined. That would somehow destroy the concept of an "azimuthal" projection. Such projections are not used in practice.

Comment: Ok, so the azimath case is tangent and there is no secant case, and for transverse cylindrical, one specify k_0 to adjust the secant line, is there a relation for e.g. to adjust the secant lines at equator to be 1/6 of width of the zone before the secant line rightside and automatic the same will be leftside?

Comment: I added an image to show what I mean

Comment: In Transverse Mercator, the scale factor generally used is 0.9996, which makes the standard circles at about 1.62° either side of the central meridian. Transverse Mercator is different from cylindrical equal-area.

Comment: The relationship would be `k_0 = acos(dLon)` where dLon is the angular separation at equator between the central meridian and the standard circles (for the spherical case).

Comment: the value for acos must be between -1 and 1, so how would it work if the dlon=4 degrees?

Comment: Oops, my bad, it's `cos`, not `acos`, so `k_0 = cos(dLon)`